# How to store real estate data in an elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I have Real Estate data. I am looking into storing it into elastic search to allow users to search the database real time.

I want to be able to let my users search by key fields like price, lot size, year-built, total bedrooms, etc. However, I also want to be able to let the user filter by keywords or amenities like "Has Pool", "Has Spa", "Parking Space", "Community"..

Additionally, I need to keep a distinct list of property type, property status, schools, community, etc so I can create drop down menu for my user to select from.

What should the stored data structure look like? How can I maintain a list of the distinct schools, community, type to use that to create drop down menu for the user to pick from?

The current data I have is basically a key/value pairs. I can clean it up and standardize it before storing it into Elastic Search but puzzled on what is considered a good approach to store this data?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your question I will provide baseline mappings and a basic query with facets/filters for you to start working with.

**Mappings**

```
PUT test_jay
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "amenities": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "description": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "location": {
        "type": "geo_point"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "status": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "type": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

We will use "keyword" field type for that fields you will be always be doing exact matches like a drop down list.

For fields we want to do only full text search like description we use type "text". In some cases like titles I want to have both field types.

I created a location geo_type field in case you want to put your properties in a map or do distance based searches, like near houses.

For amenities a keyword field type is enough to store an array of amenities.

**Ingest document**

```
POST test_jay/_doc
{
  "name": "Nice property",
  "description": "nice located fancy property",
  "location": {
    "lat": 37.371623,
    "lon": -122.003338
  },
  "amenities": [
    "Pool",
    "Parking",
    "Community"
  ],
  "type": "House",
  "status": "On sale"
}
```

Remember keyword fields are case sensitive!

**Search query**

```
POST test_jay/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "nice",
          "fields": [
            "name",
            "description"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "status": "On sale"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "amenities":"Pool"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "type": "House"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "amenities": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "amenities",
        "size": 10
      }
    },
    "status": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "status",
        "size": 10
      }
    },
    "type": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "type",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The multi match part will do a full text search in the title and description fields. You are filling this one with the regular search box.

Then the filter part is filled by dropdown lists.

**Query Response**

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.2876821,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test_jay",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "zWysGHgBLiMtJ3pUuvZH",
        "_score" : 0.2876821,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Nice property",
          "description" : "nice located fancy property",
          "location" : {
            "lat" : 37.371623,
            "lon" : -122.003338
          },
          "amenities" : [
            "Pool",
            "Parking",
            "Community"
          ],
          "type" : "House",
          "status" : "On sale"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "amenities" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "Community",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "Parking",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "Pool",
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    },
    "type" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "House",
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    },
    "status" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "On sale",
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

With the query response you can fill the facets for future filters.

I recommend you to play around with this and then come back with more specific questions.

Comment: Your help is much appreciated! What about other information like address, Price, ListedDate, etc. Is there a limits of how much I should store in elasticsearch? I am thinking to store all the MLS data directly into the elasticsearch with no RDBM. Also, what about storing the status field to be able to create drop down menu.

Comment: Elasticsearch has a 1000 fields limit so you will be good. I think you can follow the same guidelines : If you want to do full-text search use "text" type. If you want to create a dropdown list with that use "keyword" type.  For prices elasticsearch recommends using scaled_float but any number type will allow you to do range queries https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/number.html

Comment: so for any keyword type like status, type, community would be stored into a different endpoint/index so it can be retrieve as a distinct list? what about being able to restrict the connecting user to a submit of the data? like if I have a source field, can I say user A can only search source A and B where user B can only search source B?

Comment: If you look the query I posted in the response at the end you can see the "aggregations" . Each bucket key is a unique value for that field, and the doc_count field is the amount of documents that has that field value.

That way you can build the typical facet

[X] Status 1 (22) 
[X] Status 2 (10) 

Where 22 and 10 are the amount of documents

Comment: I didnt get the second question. It is much easier when you actually say what you want to do instead of saying "user A search source B" . You can add an extra field by source, or create different indices. It;s hard to say without context

Comment: In regard the aggregations, wouldn't that mean I would have to query the entire dataset to get the values? if I have 50m documents, I would have to query all that every time to get the distinct list, wouldn't it be better to store that data into a separate index? like before the user search, I can display the available options in a menu.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229703/discussion-between-jay-and-llermaly).